# Evaluation nested too deeply when using reference class with active binding

Tags: r, reference-class

Reproducible example:

```
bed2_RC <- methods::setRefClass(

  "bed2",

  fields = list(
    .fam = "data.frame",

    #### Active bindings
    fam = function() {
      if (ncol(.self$.fam) == 0) {
        .self$.fam <- datasets::iris
      }
      .self$.fam
    },

    nrow = function() print(nrow(.self$fam))
  )
)

bed2 <- function() new(Class = "bed2")
bed2()
```

Error message:

```
Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?
Error during wrapup: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?
```

I don't get why there is an infinite loop happening here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hum, when using `nrow(.self$fam)`, it actually tries to call the active binding `$nrow()`, not the base function. Replacing with `base::nrow(.self$fam)` works as expected.

Comment: @Oliver I can't validate my answer before two days.